# Not responding gestures UITableVIew editActionsForRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapbox

I am currently trying to add edit functionality to the tableView inside a View Controller.
This view controller is added on top of a parent ViewController which is a MapView (Mapbox).

Currently, I can scroll the tableView up and down with Vertical scrolling without any issue.
However, the horizontal swipe to bring up actions on a TableViewCell results in the mapview scrolling its position.
I cannot find a while to ignore the scrolling gestures of the mapview.
Disabling scrolling of the map also does not fix the issue. TableView Editing code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let test1 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Test1") { (_, indexPath) in

    }

    test1 = UIColor=.red

    let test2 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Test2") { (_, indexPath) in

    }

    test2 = UIColor.blue

    return [test1, test2]
}
```

And the function that adds the UIViewController containing the TableView on top of the Mapview:

```
self.detailView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height,    width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
self.view.addSubview(self.detailView!)
self.detailViewController = TestViewController()

self.detailViewController!.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.detailView?.addSubview(self.detailViewController!.view)
self.addChildViewController(self.detailViewController!)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
     self.detailView?.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Comment: I have noticed a similar issue in my own app (which brought me here). From what I can tell, the "begin editing" trigger of the swipe is very inconsistent. I have my best luck when starting a swipe from the far right edge of the screen/table cell. I have looked into raywenderlich's article on swiping table cells, but they claim it is deprecated by the UITableViewRowAction, which you and I agree is insufficient in it's default form. Best of luck finding a better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have pieced together a few different answers which combined seemed to solve my problem.

First:

Ensure your editing delegates are configured - note the editingStyleForRow differences

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // handle your data source changes here
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // This is important, as the editing behavior changes the editing style for some reason?

    return tableView.isEditing ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone: UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

Second:

Ensure your gestures are not intercepted. I added this category to my UIViewController hosting my UITableView:

```
@interface UIView (CellSwipeAdditions)
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
@end

@implementation UIView (CellSwipeAdditions)
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
        return YES;
    }
@end
```

Comment: I attempted to use your implementation as well, but was still unsuccessful. Thank you for the help though. I ended up using [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) and it works without issue.

Comment: I was about to use MGSwipeTableCell as well, and then I made the edit above from UITableView to UIView and it seemed to have fix it! Apparently, any gesture recognizer anywhere in the view hierarchy can intercept and block the swipe to delete action. Glad you got it working and thank you for the rep!